# Hide / Show link changing with content.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/gCm7w/

I have hidden text that is revealed by clicking on the [ + ] sign.

The [ + ] changes to [ - ] when the hidden text is revealed, and changes back to [ + ] when it is hidden again using this code:

```
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();

    if($(this).parent().next().is(':hidden'))
    {
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    }
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == '[ + ]' ? "[ - ]" : "[ + ]");
    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

However if one clicks the other hidden text to reveal it without closing the previous text, the previous text is hidden but the [ - ] does not change back to [ + ], how do I edit my code to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8L3zQ/)</kbd>

```
$('.more').not(this).text('[ + ]');
```

set text of all button to `[ + ]` expect the current button .

[.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

[this keyword/](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)